# Loading block via ajax

Tags: 8, blocks, ajax

I have an custom module with Block:

```
namespace Drupal\generator\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class GeneratorBlock extends BlockBase {
    
    public function build() {
        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\generator\Form\ProjektForm');
        
        return array(
          'form' => $form,
          '#attached' => array(
            'library' =>  array(
              'generator/generator-css'
            ),
          ),
        );

    }
}
```

All it does is placing some From in there with additional `.css` file (from library). I can place this block via Admin -> Structure -> Block layout and it works fine.

What I want now is to **load that block via Ajax** (because I want to refresh the whole block in some cases). And by that I mean I want to load it into wrapper (like with `$.load(...)`) or get the content of the block in JS variable (not the whole page with block, but just the rendered block).

I've found the tutorial for Drupal 7 on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/simple-drupal-ajax-load-with-jquery-and-delivery-callback), but I failed to port it to Drupal 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `#ajax` attribute to load main part of the block via Drupal ajax.

```
namespace Drupal\generator\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\generator\Form\ProjektForm;

class GeneratorBlock extends BlockBase {

  public function build() {
    return array(
      'form_wrapper' => array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="form-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#markup' => '',
      ),
      'load_form' => array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => $this->t('Load form'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'wrapper' => 'form-wrapper',
          'callback' => array(static::class, 'getForm'),
        ),
      ),
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' =>  array(
          'generator/generator-css'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  public static function getForm() {
    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ProjektForm::class);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, was wondering if there is a way to load this without the use of the button. Like render the block automatically after the page has been loaded fully.

Comment: The easiest way would be to hide the button with css and trigger it with JavaScript when the page finished loading.